# EMGUCV Multiple webcam

Tags: c#, webcam, emgucv

i am trying to use 3 cameras to capture photos however i am unable to produce all 3 of it. i have 2 external webcam ( Microsoft Cinema Webcam ) and 1 internal laptop camera , i used my previous laptop and it works perfectly however when i tried to use another laptop it is unable to work.

I tried some ways like testing each camera and i found out that i can use only 2 webcam at the same time using my program despite having 3 at the other laptop.

I am unable to make my laptop camera work . Any idea how?

Any idea how to get this work?

> ```
> namespace Camera
> {
>     public partial class CameraOutput : Form
>     {
>         private Capture _capture, _capture2, _capture3;
>         private bool captureInProgress;
>         private bool saveToFile;
>
>         private Font font = new Font("Calibri", 14);
>
>         public CameraOutput()
>         {
>             InitializeComponent();
>         }
>
>         private void ProcessFrame(Object sender, EventArgs arg)
>         {
>             Image<Bgr, Byte> ImageFrame = _capture.QueryFrame();
>             Image<Bgr, Byte> ImageFrame2 = _capture2.QueryFrame();
>             Image<Bgr, Byte> ImageFrame3 = _capture3.QueryFrame();
>
>             CamImageBox.Image = ImageFrame;
>             CamImageBox2.Image = ImageFrame3;
>             CamImageBox3.Image = ImageFrame2;
>
>
>             //image_Form1 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\center90\center90(1).jpg");
>
>
>             if (saveToFile)
>             {
>                 ImageFrame.Save(@"C:\Users\L31101\Desktop\Camera\Camera\bin\Debug\left\left.jpg");
>                 ImageFrame3.Save(@"C:\Users\L31101\Desktop\Camera\Camera\bin\Debug\center\center.jpg");
>                 ImageFrame2.Save(@"C:\Users\L31101\Desktop\Camera\Camera\bin\Debug\right\right.jpg");
>                 //System.Drawing.Image img = ImageFrame3.ToBitmap();
>                 //image_Form1 = img;
>                 CameraCoordinates form2 = new CameraCoordinates(ImageFrame3.ToBitmap(),ImageFrame.ToBitmap(),ImageFrame2.ToBitmap());
>                 form2.Show();
>                 saveToFile = !saveToFile;
>             }
>
>
>         }
>
>         private void CameraOutput_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>         {
>             #region if capture is not created, create it now
>
>             pictureBox1.Enabled = true;
>
>             if (_capture == null)
>             {
>                 try
>                 {
>                     _capture = new Capture(1);
>                 }
>
>                 catch (NullReferenceException excpt)
>                 {
>                     MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message);
>                 }
>             }
>
>             if (_capture2 == null)
>             {
>                 try
>                 {
>                     _capture2 = new Capture(2);
>                 }
>
>                 catch (NullReferenceException excpt)
>                 {
>                     MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message);
>                 }
>             }
>
>             if (_capture3 == null)
>             {
>                 try
>                 {
>                     _capture3 = new Capture(3);
>                 }
>
>                 catch (NullReferenceException excpt)
>                 {
>                     MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message);
>                 }
>             }
>             #endregion
>
>             if (_capture != null)
>             {
>                 if (pictureBox1.Enabled == false)
>                 {
>                     Application.Idle -= ProcessFrame;
>                 }
>                 else
>                 {
>                     Application.Idle += ProcessFrame;
>                 }
>
>                 captureInProgress = !captureInProgress;
>             }
>
>             if (_capture2 != null)
>             {
>                 if (pictureBox1.Enabled == false)
>                 {
>                     Application.Idle -= ProcessFrame;
>                 }
>                 else
>                 {
>                     Application.Idle += ProcessFrame;
>                 }
>
>                 captureInProgress = !captureInProgress;
>             }
>
>             if (_capture3 != null)
>             {
>                 if (pictureBox1.Enabled == false)
>                 {
>                     Application.Idle -= ProcessFrame;
>                 }
>                 else
>                 {
>                     Application.Idle += ProcessFrame;
>                 }
>
>                 captureInProgress = !captureInProgress;
>             }
>         }
>
>         private void ReleaseData()
>         {
>             if (_capture != null)
>             _capture.Dispose();
>
>             if (_capture2 != null)
>                 _capture.Dispose();
>
>             if (_capture3 != null)
>                 _capture.Dispose();
>         }
>
>         Image image_Form1;
>         public Image Image_Form1
>         {
>             get { return image_Form1; }
>             set { image_Form1 = value; }
>         }
>
>         private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>         {
>             saveToFile = !saveToFile;
>             MessageBox.Show("Done");
>         }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

> _capture = new Capture(1);

You're indexing from 1, should you be indexing from 0?